# Husky 5 .huskey gitignore

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gitignore, husky

10 days ago, Husky 5 was released
https://dev.to/typicode/what-s-new-in-husky-5-32g5

after migrating to it (https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/)

I've noticed that there is a new `.husky` dir in the project.

by default it contains the following:

```
.huskey
   -> .gitignore
   -> /_
```

the `.gitignore` file is simply ignoring the `_` dir

```
_
```

and inside the `/_` dir there is a `huskey.sh` file which is obviously meant to be ignored.

in the documentation - you add hook by:

```
npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npm test"
```

which will create a `pre-commit` file inside the `.husky` dir.

Should I commit that dir with the `pre-commit` file? not sure about that and can't find that in documentation.

Comment: You should commit not-auto created files. If you always need to add that file, then commit. But usually you do not commit any dir that contains `.` prefix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want those hooks to be standard for your repo then yes you will need to commit them. For example, if you have a commit-msg hook to lint commit messages and you want other developers cloning your repo to adhere to those lint rules then the `commit-msg` file is the way to enforce that.